# How to add transparent own output capturing to Python program?

Tags: python, logging, stdout, io-redirection

I have a `Python` script which consists of many modules, which do some printouts. Some printouts are made with the help of `logging` module, others -- with the help of `print` function. Some output goes to `stdout`, other goes to `stderr`.

Now I want to capture all program's output into log file, but do it transparently for the user, i.e. so the user still see outputs.

Also I want to do this by means of Python, not by means of shell scripting, because I want program to name log file itself and save it into specific place.

How can I do that?